# POST URL in power builder

Tags: string, powerbuilder, powerbuilder-conversion

- I am working in Powerbuilder technology.

  - An OLE web browser object is defined in a window of the Powerbuilder.

Expected scenerio: Data from the Powerbuilder window will be passed to the server where the data will be parsed and a report will be generated which will be viewed in the OLE object in the powerbuilder window.

**Steps taken:**

- Used powerbuilder's PostURL method to send the data to the server
- While sending data from the Powerbuilder window to the server, the data is XML structure that i need to sand to WS

**Problem**

i get error -1

here is the code:

```
string ls_ret  = ''
InternetResult ls_result
blob urldata
urldata = blob("")
string urlname = "http://secure.telemessage.com/partners/xmlMessage.jsp"
long ll_ret, ll_length
 string ls
 ls =  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><TELEMESSAGE><TELEMESSAGE_CONTENT><MESSAGE><MESSAGE_INFORMATION><SUBJECT></SUBJECT></MESSAGE_INFORMATION><USER_FROM><CIML><NAML><LOGIN_DETAILS><USER_NAME>carelaser</USER_NAME><PASSWORD>11235813</PASSWORD></LOGIN_DETAILS></NAML></CIML></USER_FROM><MESSAGE_CONTENT><TEXT_MESSAGE><MESSAGE_INDEX>0</MESSAGE_INDEX><TEXT>test 1</TEXT> </TEXT_MESSAGE></MESSAGE_CONTENT> <USER_TO><CIML><DEVICE_INFORMATION> <DEVICE_TYPE DEVICE_TYPE="SMS"/><DEVICE_VALUE>0502201630</DEVICE_VALUE></DEVICE_INFORMATION></CIML></USER_TO></MESSAGE></TELEMESSAGE_CONTENT><VERSION>1.6</VERSION></TELEMESSAGE>'
ll_length = Len(ls)
string urlheader = "Content-Type: application/xml~n"
urlheader +="Content-Length: " + String(ll_length) + "~n~n"
 urldata =blob(ls)

GetContextService("Internet", iinet_base)
messagebox("urlname", urlname)
messagebox("urlheader", urlheader)
messagebox("urldata",string(urldata))
ll_ret = iinet_base.posturl(urlname, urldata , urlheader, ls_result)
messagebox("Return: " + string(ll_ret) ,string(ls_result))
```

Return ls_ret

Comment: What does Fiddler show the outgoing message to be?

Comment: TopWiz has a library here that might help: http://www.topwizprogramming.com/freecode_winhttp.html

Comment: what is Fiddler  ?

Comment: I can see one problem, I believe PostURL is asynchronous so you need to add code to the INet object (you need to inherit from if not already) and there will be an event triggered when the URL returns.